# Communication between containers via host.docker.internal

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-network, podman

I got the following situation:
ngnix <-> nodejs

These are 2 containers that need to communicate together.

My nginx.conf has an upstream setting to set the location of the nodejs:

```
upstream website {
   server host.docker.internal:30401;
}
```

My problem is that sometimes I need to run my nodejs not in a container but directly on the host for development purposes.

When my nodejs app runs directly on the host, my nginx config works perfectly.

The issue is when I run my nodejs in a container my ngnix cannot reach my nodejs container.
My nodejs is exposing the 30401 port and I'm using the default bridge network and also using docker-compose.

I expected that since my nodejs exposed a port, my nginx should be able to reach `host.docker.internal:30401` since the port is bound on my host IP in both cases (containerized or not).

But it doesn't work, I'm I missing something?

Additional info: I'm on windows using podman and docker-compose

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly how you're starting things up.